# Change WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(); with a function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change this `WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();` with a function in my child theme. So when user check the cart, the shipping calculator show options just for `CL` country.

Comment: I found a solution explain in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution. Set the country and shipping country at the moment to add to cart.

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart' , 'set_country_befor_cart_page'); 

function set_country_befor_cart_page(){
    WC()->customer->set_country('CL'); // CL is to set country code of default country
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('CL'); //CL is to set country code of default country
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use

```
WC()->customer->shipping_country
```

instead of

```
WC()->customer->get_shipping_country()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please add a reference website link to help other new developers to understand better.